# Stored Procedure call from Java - FUNCTION does not exist?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I created a very simple stored proc using the MySQL employees demo database that should return a value:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_GetEmployeeNo`(IN i_last_name VARCHAR(16))
BEGIN
SELECT emp_no FROM employees WHERE last_name = i_last_name;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to call this procedure from a java program like so:

```
package test_mysql_demo_sp;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Test_mysql_demo_sp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        String jdbcUrl;
        jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees";
        String username = "TestUser";
        String password = "abc123";
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);

            CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{?= call usp_GetEmployeeNo(?)}");
            cStmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
            cStmt.setString(2, "Smith");
            cStmt.execute();       
            System.out.println(cStmt.getInt(1));
            cStmt.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // handle any errors
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }

    }

}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
SQLException: FUNCTION employees.usp_GetEmployeeNo does not exist
SQLState: 42000
VendorError: 1305
```

I can call the procedure from MySQL workbench with the same user and it returns the value just fine. Is the java code incorrect? Is the procedure created correctly? Is this a permission issue? (I've granted the user pretty much all permissions) Any ideas would be appreciated as I've spent several days trying to solve this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL stored procedure doesn't return any value, but the result of a select statement inside of stored procedure can be read after execution.

However, you need a function to return a single value, so you must change your SQL code to a MySQL function declaration:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `usp_GetEmployeeNo`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `usp_GetEmployeeNo`(i_last_name VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN

    declare return_val int default 0;  /* local variable */

    SELECT emp_no 
      into return_val  /* <-- */
    FROM employees 
    WHERE last_name = i_last_name;

    return return_val;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```